# SharePoint 2010 Webpart Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, error, id

I am accessing a list view webpart and seeing an error:

> **Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator. Correlation
>   ID:297fcf5a-a4b4-4266-a62e-a50424951505**

I checked the logs against this ID and found this:

> Error while executing web part: System.Exception: ResolveToken
>   returned unexpected object type.      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.MethodCollection.MethodDescription.SetCode(DynamicILInfo
>   ilInfo, Int32[] fixup, Byte[] ilCode, Byte[] ehTable, Int32
>   maxStackSize, MethodCollection methodColl)      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.MethodCollection.MethodDescription.DefineDynamicMethod(DynamicMethod
>   dm, MethodCollection methodColl)      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.MethodCollection.CreateDynamicMethods()      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.MethodCollection.GetMethodInfoInternal(Int32
>   methodNumber)      at
>   Microsoft.Xslt.MethodCollection.GetMethodInfo(Int32 methodNumber)
>   at Microsoft.Xslt.STransform.GetCompiledTransform()      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BaseXsltListWebPart.LoadXslCompiledTransform(WSSXmlUrlResolver
>   someXmlResolver)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXslCompiledTransform()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)

The strange thing is this happens only on 1WFE of the 6 we have. I connected to the same on other WFE's and it works just fine. Our SP 2010 versions is 14.0.7196.5000

*Any help is much appreciated.
Vj*

Comment: Are you getting this error for all lists or just one particular list? Also check the Web part gallery for list web part is available or not?

Comment: This happens only for that webpart and only on one WFE. All other wfe's behave normally.

Comment: Update. Recycling of Appool fixed the issue.

Comment: You can answer your own question. How you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When something works on one server and not others I find that quite often it is related to the permissions on the server (usually temp folder). Try this Get the SysInternals and fire the process monitor. Enable filter with Result contains Denied. And try to recreate the issue. The reasons for access denied my differ (app pool running under wrong identity, App pool not member of the WSS_WPG group etc). If it is not access denied you can use procMon to dig further into what the worker process is doing. Find the id of the process for you web app and set the filter in procMon against that process. Comparing execution with front end that works may point where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Since, this was happening only on one of the wfe, the nightly appool recycle fixed the issue. The list is rendering just fine now.